# what's the correct way of pulling from a JSON file with jQuery/plain JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

**Solved**

Turns out I messed up my JSON while trying to fix it. Thanks for helping. Showed me some new methods to use json :)

I searched through a lot of other questions, tried the responses, some did something others just threw an error. If it worked, it logged this whole list of metadata (including the json data I want) to the console:

```
{…}
​
abort: function abort(e)​
always: function always()​
catch: function catch(e)​
done: function add()​
fail: function add()​
getAllResponseHeaders: function getAllResponseHeaders()​
getResponseHeader: function getResponseHeader(e)​
overrideMimeType: function overrideMimeType(e)​
pipe: function pipe()​
progress: function add()​
promise: function promise(e)
​
readyState: 4
​
responseText: "<JSON content>"
​
setRequestHeader: function setRequestHeader(e, t)​
state: function state()
​
status: 200
​
statusCode: function statusCode(e)
​
statusText: "OK"
​
then: function then(t, n, r)​
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

So, my question is: how do I get the json contents from this?

Code used:

```
function start() {
  var j = $.ajax({
    url: 'users.json',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
}
```

Json:

```
        "UsersByID":[ {
                "id": 1
                "Name": ["K", "L", "Smiths"],
                "Birthday": ["03", "10", "1987"],
                "Username": "user1",
                "Password": "verysafepassword",
                "Hollidays": [{
                        "HollidayId": 1
                        "HollidayType": 2,
                        "AmountOfPeople": 5,
                        "Date": ["18", "08", "2020"]
                        }{
                        "HollidayId": 2
                        "HollidayType": 3,
                        "AmountOfPeople": 2,
                        "Date": ["24", "10", "2020"]
                        }

                }]

        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: So your `data` **is** json

Comment: yes the file 'users.json' is a json file. it does show up when i log the response, but the response i get is a full list of all meta-data associated with the file, but i'd like to only get the json contents.

Comment: You return Ajax object, not response. Google more about async requests and how to get response from it. You need to use callback instead of normal `return` - your `var j` is useless and you should not use it

Comment: Are you sure that what you have quoted is the result of the `console.log(data);` statement in the question?

Comment: @Quetin yes it is, might be something todo with my json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you normally do (in plain javascript) is to filter throughthe delivered JSON. Since I do not know what you want to filter, some pseudo code how it works:

```
   function start() {
     var j = $.ajax({
       url: 'users.json',
       type: "GET",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (response) { //data is a keyword so better use response
         console.log(response);

        response.data.forEach(function(field) { // we iterate through each field in the JSON
         if (field.typeField == "UsersByID") {  // Given the JSON part looks like {"UsersByID":{"myBigData": "secrets","yourBigData": "noSecrets"}}
        console.info("My content found"); 
        // Do whatever you have to do with the content
        }
      }); // for each END

    }
  });
}
```

**EDITT** To process the JSON there are different posibilities If you know what is comming you filter like I have done above and then do something with the result.
Another way if you don't have to extract, but the whole response is the needed JSON you do as follows (and of course you can combine)

```
function start() {
     var j = $.ajax({
       url: 'users.json',
       type: "GET",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (response) { //data is a keyword so better use response
         console.log(response);
         var myObj = JSON.parse(response);
        // Do whatever you have to do with myObj e.g.
       var u_username = myObj.Username; // you retrieve from the object with the field names
  // when nested you get a new object and then you retrieve
    var objHollidays = myObj.Hollidays;
    var u_HollidayId = objHollidays.HollidayId;
    // OR you iterate over all objHollidays 
    objHollidays.HollidayId.forEach(function(field) { // we iterate through each 
        //Do whatever you need
       });
    }
  });
}
```

Parsing Dates
Date objects are not allowed in JSON.
If you need to include a date, write it as a string.
You can convert it back into a date object later:

```
 var text = '{ "name":"John", "birth":"1986-12-14", "city":"New York"}';
 var obj = JSON.parse(text);
 obj.birth = new Date(obj.birth);
```

Comment: added to main question.
don't worry about encryption, it's all fake data :)